# Bootstrap table td squeezing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd use your advice how to get rid of that table  squeezing.

```
 <div class="container">
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover" name="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">20.09.2015</td>
                <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><span class="label label-default label-as-badge" style="font-weight:normal;">category</span></a></td>
                <td class="col-md-5"><a id="test" name="test" href="#">41423</a></td>
                <td class="col-md-5">1123</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
```

What I would like to accomplish is to two left-side td's - date, and category always the same, small ones, not squeezable. And two right-side td's with title and content beginning should be more less the same.

Now if I'd drag the right side of the browser, it should shrink all whats possible, and if no space left, then cutting (elippsing or smth) from the right side, to the left side.

Is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a `td` (or any element) from wrapping when the window is made smaller, use `white-space: nowrap` for a style. This will make sure lines break only at `<br>` elements.

See [official documentation at W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space).